# Calling webservice through a proxy

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, proxy, wsdl

I want to call a webservice .
I created a webservice client in netbeans, and gave WSDL url.
It generated the classes for me.
Where can I give the proxy details, and the ws authentication paramaeters.

WSDL generation goes on fine, but while executing the client it gives me error"HTTP status code 502: Proxy Error"

I am using java 1.7, netbeans 7.3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using JAX-WS, then [this page](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html) in the NetBeans documentation says how to do it:

> "3) ... If you are behind a firewall, you might need to specify a proxy server—otherwise the WSDL file cannot be downloaded. **To specify the proxy server, click Set Proxy in the wizard. The IDE's Options window opens, where you can set the proxy universally for the IDE.**"

Comment: Actually the WSDL is downloaded succesfully, by setting proxy in IDE. But the real problem is while running the client, It does take this setting. And it gives me a proxy error.  Any suggestions please ?